# local variable 'value' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I am trying to convert this code into a function but getting "local variable 'value' referenced before assignment" as an error for two variables.
I'll paste the whole code for better understanding

```
def allocator(item_mass,item_vol,truck_mass,truck_vol,truck_cost):
    n_items = len(item_vol)
    set_items = range(n_items)
    n_trucks = len(truck_cost)
    set_trucks = range(n_trucks)

    y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('truckUsed', set_trucks,
    lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

    x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('itemInTruck', (set_items, set_trucks), 
    lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

    prob = LpProblem("Truck allocatoin problem", LpMinimize)

    prob += lpSum([truck_cost[i] * y[i] for i in set_trucks])

    for j in set_items:
        prob += lpSum([x[j][i] for i in set_trucks]) == 1

    for i in set_trucks:
        prob += lpSum([item_mass[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_mass[i]*y[i]

        prob += lpSum([item_vol[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_vol[i]*y[i]

    for j in set_items:
        for i in set_trucks:
            x[j][i] <= y[i]


    prob.solve()

    x_soln = np.array([[x[i][j].varValue for i in set_items] for j in set_trucks])
    y_soln = np.array([y[i].varValue for i in set_trucks])

    lpstatus = LpStatus[prob.status]   #these two throw the error
    value_obj = value(prob.objective)  #


    return lpstatus,value_obj
```

in the original code the commented lines were like this:

```
print (("Status:"), LpStatus[prob.status])
print ("Total Cost is: ", value(prob.objective))
```

Comment: There's nothing here that would cause that error. You've removed something critical to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function value that u use in the line

```
value_obj = value(prob.objective)
```

isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: its defined in the pulp library which the function is using